# ethernet connectivity

Tags: 18.04, ethernet

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell laptop with a dock. The wireless works fine, while the Ethernet connection does not work at all.

I have tried with device manager and setting in `/etc/network/interfaces`. DHCP tries to connect but never does. In fact, this is messing up my Spectrum modem somehow. My download speeds are 8 MBS right now when I plug in the Ethernet cable. I have to call Spectrum for them to reset something to get back to full download speed of 400M plus. This is absolutely connected to this network interface issue. I have have repeated this a few times now.

```
root@srock-Latitude-E6540:/etc/NetworkManager# lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Ethernet
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM [8086:153a] (rev 04)
        Subsystem: Dell Ethernet Connection I217-LM [1028:05be]
        Kernel driver in use: e1000e
        Kernel modules: e1000e

#/etc/network/interfaces
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet dhcp

root@srock-Latitude-E6540:/etc/NetworkManager# ifup eno1
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.5
Copyright 2004-2016 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/eno1/f8:ca:b8:5c:a0:d0
Sending on   LPF/eno1/f8:ca:b8:5c:a0:d0
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on eno1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x129e5951)

DHCPDISCOVER on eno1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0x129e5951)

DHCPDISCOVER on eno1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10 (xid=0x129e5951)

DHCPDISCOVER on eno1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14 (xid=0x129e5951)

DHCPDISCOVER on eno1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14 (xid=0x129e5951)

DHCPDISCOVER on eno1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15 (xid=0x129e5951)

DHCPDISCOVER on eno1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 18 (xid=0x129e5951)
```

Comment: problem solved.  took some getting used to network manager something I've avoided until now.  (went around it and back to old school)

Comment: Hey rockmanlinux! Do post an answer to your question. It may be helpful to the community.